# Google Cloud Run Cache no invalidated

Tags: caching, dns, browser-cache, google-cloud-run

On June 21 I changed my website to a new framework. In the past I've used Vuejs and now I'm using React. But my cache never invalidates, I can access my new site only in browsers that never enter the old version or using CTRL + SHIFT + R (But on next refresh the old site backs).

I was looking in the Chrome Dev tools network tool and noticed the response header still sends the date attribute as June 20, others clients have this same problem. How can I resolve this? Without going into browser settings and manually checking my cache, it's impracticable cause older users have this same problem too…

I also tried flush DNS Cache with this tool  https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache

It's running in Google Cloud Run

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the [revisions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/managing/revisions) of your project? You can also try this documentation to [invalidate the cache content](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/invalidating-cached-content#console).

Comment: @AndresFiescoCasasola I'm using different services on cloud run, I changed the mapping on custom domains to my main domain appoint to the new site service, it's not a revision problem. About Invalidating on cache CDN It's not possible, because both projects don't use Cloud CDN, all static files are serving in `public` folder